# Edit the command line path for an executable on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell, macports, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I have the default package of Ruby installed that shipped with the OS, which is an older version.

I have recently installed MacPorts with the latest Ruby version which is installed in a seperate location:-

```
/opt/local/bin/
```

But when I run

```
which ruby
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Is there any way to edit the path of the command **ruby** so it would reference the new installation in the /opt/ directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put `/opt/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` and maybe clear your command cache with `hash -r`.

Answer (score 1):

Well since Mac is based on Unix its a simple command Editing your config file.

you can try that

```
~/.bash_profile (Local Profile) or
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist (System Wide)
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

or you can use an alias however the which command wont work with these.

```
alias ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby
```

Hope this helps,  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) for more information effectively you are looking to set an environment variable.